On Newton-Raphson Method for Single Degree of Freedom Systems
I am trying to understand the geometric interpretation of the Newton-Raphson method as used in nonlinear structural mechanics. The fundamental governing equation of nonlinear structural mechanics is given by
$$R = F_{int} \left( u \right) - F_{ext}$$
where, for simplicity, we assume that $u$ is a scalar (single-degree-of-freedom system), keeping in mind that, in general, $u$ can be a vector for multi-degree-of-freedom systems. The above equation can be geometrically represented as a three-dimensional surface with $u$ and $F_{ext}$ being independent variables, and $R$ being the dependent variable.
Let's further assume that $F_{int} = \sin \left( u \right)$ and we want to find the displacement, $u$, corresponding to an externally applied load of 0.5 N, i.e., $F_{ext} = F_{1} = 0.5$. To start the iterative process, we assume that $u^{\left( 0 \right)} = 0.5$, where, the superscript indicates the iteration number. We can determine the residual or out-of-balance force as $R^{\left( 0 \right)} = \sin \left( u^{\left( 0 \right)} \right) - F_{1} = \sin \left( 0.5 \right) - 0.5$.
We can now draw a tangent plane to the $u-F_{ext}-R$ surface at point $\left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1}, R^{\left( 0 \right)}\right)$. The equation of this tangent plane is given by
$$R - R^{\left( 0 \right)} = \left.\dfrac{\partial R}{\partial u}\right|_{\left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1} \right)} \left( u - u^{\left( 0 \right)} \right) + \left.\dfrac{\partial R}{\partial F_{ext}}\right|_{\left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1} \right)}  \left( F_{ext} - F_1 \right)$$
$$R - R^{\left( 0 \right)} = \left.\dfrac{\partial R}{\partial u}\right|_{\left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1} \right)} \left( u - 0.5 \right) + \left.\dfrac{\partial R}{\partial F_{ext}}\right|_{\left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1} \right)} \left( F_{ext} - 0.5 \right)$$
The intersection of the above tangent plane with $R = 0$ ($u-F_{ext}$ plane) can be determined by setting $R = 0$:
$$- R^{\left( 0 \right)} = \left.\dfrac{\partial R}{\partial u}\right|_{\left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1} \right)} \left( u - 0.5 \right) + \left.\dfrac{\partial R}{\partial F_{ext}}\right|_{\left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1} \right)} \left( F_{ext} - 0.5 \right)$$
This will result in a curve in two-dimensional $u-F_{ext}$ space. Similarly, we can obtain the intersection of the above curve with $F_{ext} = F_{1}$ plane by setting $F_{ext} = 0.5$ resulting in:
$$- R^{\left( 0 \right)} = \left.\dfrac{\partial R}{\partial u}\right|_{\left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1} \right)} \left( u - 0.5 \right)$$
Finally, $\left.\dfrac{\partial R}{\partial u}\right|_{\left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1} \right)} = \left.\dfrac{\partial F_{int}}{\partial u}\right|_{\left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1} \right)} = K{\left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1} \right)}$, where, $K$ is the tangent stiffness matrix.
$$- R^{\left( 0 \right)} = K{\left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1} \right)} \left( u - 0.5 \right)$$
This equation can be solved to determine the next iterative solution $u = u^{\left( 2 \right)}$.
We can see that in Newton-Raphson method we are drawing a tangent plane at a given point, $\left(u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1}, R \left( u^{\left( 0 \right)}, F_{1} \right) \right)$, and determining its intersection with $R = 0$ and $F_{ext} = F_{1}$ planes. However, typically in structural mechanics textbooks, the Newton-Raphson method is geometrically illustrated using a tangent curve to the load-displacement curve ($u$ vs. $F_{ext}$). Assuming that the above derivation is correct, how are these two geometric interpretations related to each other? Are they equivalent; if yes, can you please elaborate?

